# How to draw a arc in android openGL ES1.1?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Using three values ​​are given on a 2D plane, as shown below, and I would like curve.

1. Starting point for the first draw (x, y, z).
2. Left Angle.
3. Right angle.

Android OpenGL ES to the above values ​​should be drawn and how do you ask for advice?

[image: Drawing]

Comment: This actually is not a good fit for OpenGL ES. Parametric things like bezier curves / path rendering can be used to implement this in OpenVG or OpenGL using tessellation, but there is no actual API feature in OpenGL ES that is going to help you draw curved polylines like this :-\ This is not to say it cannot be done, it will just require you to do things like compute the vertices on the CPU without the assistance of the API.

Comment: I feel I should add to this that iOS has APIs for path rendering, I do not have experience with Android on the matter. But Android may also, so look into this.

Comment: Thank's for your answer Andon!!

Comment: It seems to be said that there is only way to directly calculate the final.

Then, there will be an example to be aware to draw a curve?